# Unwanted underscore appears in `\path` text after dash

Tags: punctuation, underscore

An unwanted underscore displays after the dash in the text of `\path`:

```
\path{{hyphenated-text}/directory}.
```

displays in HTML output as:

> hyphenated-_text/directory

Any ideas on how to avoid this outcome ?

MWE

```
\DocumentClass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{hyphenat} 
\begin{document} 
\par Some text ... located in the \path{{blah-directory}/blah} directory. 
\end{document}
```

Reference chtml file contents:

```
% This configuration makes sure that the produced HTML fits
% the subset of HTML-tags used by the QtTextbrowser.
%
% The supported subset for Qt-4.7 can be found here:
% http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.7/richtext-html-subset.html
%
% It also cleans up all unnecessary stylesheets an span-tags.
% 

\Preamble{html, charset=utf-8}

% remove the entire default navigation bar
\Configure{crosslinks}
    {}{}{}
    {}
    {}{}{}{}
\Configure{crosslinks+}
    {}{}{}
    {}
    {}{}{}{}

% set clean paragraph tags for \par
\Configure{HtmlPar}
    { \HCode{<p>} }{ \EndP \HCode{<p>} }
    { \HCode{</p>} }{ \HCode{</p>} }

% set appropriate headings for sections
\Configure{section}
    {}{}
    {\HCode{<h2 id="">}\TitleMark\space}{\HCode{</h2>}\ShowPar \IgnoreIndent \par}
\Configure{subsection}
    {}{}
    {\HCode{<h3 id="">}\TitleMark\space}{\HCode{</h3>}\ShowPar \IgnoreIndent \par}
\Configure{subsubsection}
    {}{}
    {\HCode{<h4 id="">}\TitleMark\space}{\HCode{</h4>}\ShowPar \IgnoreIndent \par}
\Configure{paragraph}
    {}{}
    {\HCode{<h4 id="">}\TitleMark\space}{\HCode{</h4>}\ShowPar \IgnoreIndent \par}

% set clean inline tags and line breaks
\Configure{textit}{\ifvmode\ShowPar\fi\HCode{<i>}}{\HCode{</i>}}
\Configure{textbf}{\ifvmode\ShowPar\fi\HCode{<b>}}{\HCode{</b>}}
\Configure{texttt}{\ifvmode\ShowPar\fi\HCode{<tt>}}{\HCode{</tt>}}
\Configure{newline}{\ifvmode\ShowPar\fi\Tg<br />}

% remove surrounding div tags for figures and set the align attribute properly
\ConfigureEnv{figure}
    {\IgnorePar\EndP\HCode{<table class="figure" align="center"><tr><td>}\ShowPar}
    {\IgnorePar\HCode{</td></tr></table>}\ShowPar}
    {}{}

% remove surrounding rulers for figures
\Configure{float}
    {\ifOption{refcaption}{}{\csname par\endcsname\ShowPar \leavevmode}}
    {\HCode{}}
    {\ifvmode \IgnorePar \fi\EndP \HCode{}\csname par\endcsname\ShowPar}

% center captions properly and use i-tag rather than stylesheets
\Configure{caption}
    {\HCode{}\IgnorePar\EndP\HCode{<div class="caption" align="center"><i>}}
    {: } {\HCode{}}
    {\IgnorePar\EndP\HCode{</i></div>}}

% set appropriate table settings
\Configure{halignTB<>}{tabular}
    {\HCode{id="TBL-\TableNo" class="tabular" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" align="center" border="1"}<>\HAlign}

\Configure{halignTB<>}{longtable}
    {\HCode{id="TBL-\TableNo" class="longtable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" align="center"
    border="1"}<>\HAlign}

% remove unnecessary style sheet from tr-tags
\Configure{halignTR} {}

\Configure{halignTD} {}{}
    {<}{\HCode{ align="left" }}
    {-}{\HCode{ align="center" }}
    {>}{\HCode{ align="right" }}
    {l}{\HCode{ align="left" }}
    {c}{\HCode{ align="center" }}
    {r}{\HCode{ align="right" }}
    {p}{\HCode{ align="left" }}
    {}

% clean up tabular environment; removes unnecessary div-tags

\ConfigureEnv{table}
    {\ifvmode \IgnorePar\fi \EndP \HCode{<div class="table">}}
    {\ifvmode \IgnorePar\fi \EndP \HCode{</div>}\par\ShowPar}
    {}{}

\ConfigureEnv{tabular}
    {}{}{}{}

\Configure{tabular}
    {\IgnorePar\EndP \halignTB{tabular}}
    {\HCode{</table>}}
    {\HCode{\Hnewline<tr }\halignTR\HCode{>\Hnewline}}
    {\HCode{</tr>}}
    {\HCode{<td }\halignTD\HCode{>}\ShowPar}
    {\IgnorePar\HCode{</td>}\ShowPar}

\ConfigureEnv{longtable}
    {}{}{}{}

\Configure{longtable}
    {\IgnorePar\EndP \halignTB{longtable}}
    {\HCode{</table>}}
    {\HCode{\Hnewline<tr }\halignTR\HCode{>\Hnewline}}
    {\HCode{</tr>}}
    {\HCode{<td }\halignTD\HCode{>}\ShowPar}
    {\IgnorePar\HCode{</td>}\ShowPar}

% ignore \hline
\Configure{hline}{}


\Configure{multicolumn}
    {}{}{}{}

% This part is taken from the original html4.4ht of tex4ht.
% Only a <b> tag is added here to get the correct font-weight working
\ConfigureEnv{lstlisting}
    {\ifvmode \IgnorePar\fi \EndP
     \gHAdvance\listingN by 1
     \HCode{<!--l. \the\inputlineno-->}%
     \gdef\start:LstLn{%
        \HCode{<div class="lstlisting" id="listing-\listingN" style="font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;"><b>}%
        \gdef\start:LstLn{\leavevmode\special{t4ht@+\string&{35}x00A0{59}}x%
\HCode{<br />}}}
        \bgroup
    \Configure{listings}
        {{\everypar{}\leavevmode}}
        {{\everypar{}\leavevmode}}
        {\start:LstLn \HCode{<span class="label">}}
        {\HCode{</span>}}%
    }
    {\egroup
        \ifvmode \IgnorePar\fi \EndP \HCode{</b></div>}\par}
    {} {}

\begin{document}
    \CssFile
    /* mycss.sty */
    body {
        font-family: "Times New Roman";
        font-size: 11pt;
    }

    h1, h2, h3, h4 {
        font-family: Arial;
    }

    h1 {
        font-size: 48pt;
    }

    h2 {
        font-size: 18pt;
    }

    h3 {
        font-size: 14pt;
    }

    h4 {
        font-size: 13pt;
    }

    div.caption {
        font-size: 9pt;
        font-weight: normal;
    }

    a {
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    span.texttt {
        font-family: monospace;
    }
    \EndCssFile
\EndPreamble
```

Comment: How are you creating the HTML output?

Comment: @Thruston We use tex4ht component to generate the html and a script is used to post process the html output for our website

Comment: Ive checked the html output and ther eis nothing to indicate how the underscore ends up there: <span class=
         "path">{Installation-_directory}/examples</span>
         directory.

Comment: Can you please include a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that generates the wrong output?

Comment: Is this adequate as an MWE?

>\begin{document}
>\par
>Some text ... located in the
>\path{{blah-directory}/blah} directory.
>\end{document}

Comment: @Skillmon - dont seem to have formatting options in the comment box

Comment: @RobertWerner document class? It has to be in a form that we can just run out of the box without further addo.

Comment: @Skillmon 
\DocumentClass{article}
\begin{document}
\par
Some text ... located in the
\path{{blah-directory}/blah} directory.
\end{document}

Comment: @RobertWerner how is `\path` defined? Do you load any packages? What options do you specify for the `tex4ht` call?

Comment: @RobertWerner and I think it should be `\documentclass`, not `\DocumentClass`.

Comment: @Skillmon, im investigating the other questions but in the meantime, i see there are quite a few packages but none i would specifically presume to have an impact in this case. Most of them look to be standard packages. Are there any specifc types of packages you suspect might impact this ?

Comment: @RobertWerner `\path` is undefined in a minimal setup. So you have to have something that defines it. Please edit your question to have a minimal setup that actually *works* (in that it results in the erroneous output you get, without us having to guess what is missing from it).

Comment: @Skillmon I am new to this so please bear with me. I'm not a coder so this is a learning curve for me. I have updated the original question and included three \usepakcages which i would imagine are likely to be where \path is defined but you can correct me if im wrong about that and I will dig further. We use Tex Live 2015 on an Ubuntu 16.04 machine. Thank you for your time and patience with this.

Comment: @RobertWerner can you please also include your call to build the HTML output (so the `tex4ht` call)? Also, what is `\DocumentClass`? In standard LaTeX it should be `\documentclass`.

Comment: @Skillmon the call to build the html output is: `htlatex userguide-product.tex "inc/chtml,2,index=1,css-in,sec-filename,NoFonts,charset=iso-8859" "" "" "-halt-on-error"

Comment: @RobertWerner what are the contents of the file `inc/chtml`? We still can't run your example this way.

Comment: @Skillmon Added chtml file contents to original post. Hope this helps

Comment: Why do you have in the input the additional braces around the directory? What happens if you remove them?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - Even without the additional braces, same issue occurs with the underscore after the dash

Comment: And what happens if you remove the hyphenat package?

Comment: no joy without hyphenat package

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Tried it without the hyphenat package but the issue remaiins. tried with and without {} braces.

Comment: Then make a real minimal example, including the names of all the files and the exact command you use to convert to html, check in some test folder that it really reproduce the problem  (`\DocumentClass` looks dubious ...) and then update your question with this info.

Comment: what would you need to try to reproduce?
I know that the "\DocumentClass should be "\documentclass" but aside from that, what esle do oyu need in addition to the chtml.cfg listed above and the command we use to compile: htlatex userguide-product.tex "inc/chtml,2,index=1,css-in,sec-filename,NoFonts,charset=iso-8859" "" "" "-halt-on-error"

Comment: @Skillmon asked if i was using tex4ht to build the html at the beginning of thi thread. Given that it apparently has osme ohter issues, could thta be where the problem lies ?